# ALL sql with subquery, and NOT exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Im doing a sql problem and the question is this:

Get all the ship's classes of Russia. If there are no classes of Russia in the database, get all the classes in the database.
Result set: country, class

3 answers (#3 is wrong):

1. `select country, class from Classes 
    where country = ALL(select country from Classes 
                     where country='Russia')`
2. `select country, class
   from classes
   where not exists (select country
                    from classes
                    where country='Russia')
     or country='Russia'`
3. `select distinct country, class
   from classes
   where country not in(select country
                    from classes
                    where country='Russia')
     or country='Russia'`

Can anyone explain how the "ALL example works", I dont fully understand how this covers all the cases above: finding only russian classes and if none all the others.

Can anoyone also explain how ans2 and wrong ans3 is different, I think it might have something to do with null values but im not too sure..im quite new to sql

Comment: I don't like that tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all is a comparison to all values in the subquery and I don't think the way you are using it is very useful.

It would be much more useful for a numerical comparison like greater than, less than, etc.

From the MySQL site:
`SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 > ALL (SELECT s1 FROM t2);`

This would select all the s1's from t1 that are greater than **all** of the s1's from t2.

**Your example**

Your example: `select country, class from Classes where country = ALL(select country from Classes where country='Russia')` this subquery is only returning a bunch of rows of 'Russia' as you're only selecting country where country equals Russia.

However, ALL, as documented in Oracle (not documented in MySQL) will return a true condition if no values are present allowing you to select all from Russia unless no Russia rows exist.

Comment: Actually you are wrong about the ALL query in this example, I actually tested it and it works.

As i mentioned the All sql code: finds all the russian classes and if there arent any russian classes, it will find all the other classes. This is where i am having troubles understanding why it works.

Comment: I don't see any real reason why that would work except for the fact that a NULL result would return unknown rather than just false according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html.  I don't think that is how it was to be used though.

Comment: I did some more digging, MySQL doesn't document that functionality but if the subquery returns NULL or no value then the condition will return true.  Thus, allowing it to complete your functionality.  I don't see very many real life uses for that type of functionality but that is how it works I suppose.

Comment: Like you said,
select country from Classes where country='Russia'
IF there is no country with Russia, then this subquery will be empty, maybe NULL??????
Then the inital query: select country, class from Classes where country = ALL(...) somehow finds EVERY Country

Comment: If what you are saying is true, how come when the subquery returns a null or no value, the initial query will find all the other countries...wouldnt it find all the countries that are empty or null instead?

Comment: I'll try to explain: `country = ALL(select country from Classes where country='Russia')` is the condition.  So the WHERE keyword looks for that entire condition to be true.  ALL works by comparing against all the values in the subquery unless there are no values in the subquery.  The condition is TRUE if it matches 'Russia' or if there are no rows.  So if there are no rows, that condition will always be true thus matching every row of the parent query from Classes.